# Where's my Bitcoin Cash? We followed Coinbase's advice and moved our BTC into a Jaxx wallet- No Bitcoin Cash anywhere to be found

Tags: bitcoin-cash, wallet-recovery

We followed Coinbase's advice and moved our BTC into a Jaxx wallet-until the fork happened, then moved it back into Coinbase, then Gdax.
We never saw any evidence of Bitcoin Cash on either our Jaxx wallet or on Coinbase/Gdax. How do we find it?  And retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Cash is an altcoin. You must have a wallet that supports Bitcoin Cash in order to see your Bitcoin Cash.

Comment: Just grab any wallet that supports bitcoin cash and load the keys from your Jaxx wallet into it.